# Able to access internet through firefox but not chrome, or any other software

Tags: windows-7

I am able to access webpages through Firefox but not chrome, antivirus, instant messaging etc.

This is truly bizarre, when I try to install AV software it says you do not have an internet connection, while I can access websites fine on Firefox.

Chrome fails to display any webpages.

My internet connection is good and the system tray icon doesn't indicate any problems.

Comment: Perhaps you have a system proxy that's overridden in Firefox but nowhere else. What do you see under "Configure Proxies to Access the Internet" if you go to Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Settings... in Firefox? If it's not already, what happens if you switch it to "Use System Proxy Settings"?

Comment: What happens when you ping an IP address, such as Google's DNS server `8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your connection ?  Its entirely probable that something upstream from you is limiting/filtering the connection - Firefox may be getting round it via a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox uses its own proxy settings, if set, different from the rest of the system. To check this:

1. Edit, Preferences
2. Advanced, Network, Proxy Settings
3. See what it's set to. Write them down.

Then go to Start, Control Panel, Internet Options (you may need to exit category view first). In here, choose Connections, then Advanced under Proxy Settings.

If Firefox uses a proxy server, type it in here. If it auto detects the proxy settings, or didn't use one at all, then choose those options.

If these settings match, or Firefox uses the System Settings, then we need to dig deeper.

Can you ping a website by name? What about by ip address?